# Writing an image

Tags: image, matlab, save

I have an image as a result of an algorithm, that, when I want to `imshow`, I have to type the following:

```
imshow(img,[])
```

or, otherwise, I get a blank image.

How can I `imwrite` such image, as if I use `imwrite(img, 'img.png','png')`, I get a blank image.

Thanks.

Comment: By 'blank', do you mean white?

Comment: data type.  Check your data range and read the docs to see what is expected for different data types.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to clipping of the pixel intensity. When you display with `[]` as the range, `imshow` automatically scales the intensity to the full range.

Try:

```
imwrite(imadjust(img), 'img.png', 'png');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I tried your solution, I still get a `white` background